# Python: [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Invalid string or buffer length. SQLCODE=-11071 when I fetch data

Tags: python-3.x, informix

When I try to retreive my table in informix with [ifxpy](https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy) package, I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b0557e7f099b> in <module>
     16 while dictionary != False:
     17         tph.append(dictionary)
---> 18         dictionary = IfxPy.fetch_assoc(stmt)
     19 print(pd.DataFrame(tph))

Exception: [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Invalid string or buffer length. SQLCODE=-11071
```

This is my code:

```
import IfxPy
import pandas as pd
ConStr = "SERVER=informix1;DATABASE=ir_fmois;HOST=127.0.0.1;SERVICE=9092;UID=informix;PWD=1234;"
# netstat -a | findstr  9088
try:
    # netstat -a | findstr  9088
    conn = IfxPy.connect( ConStr, "", "")
except Exception as e:
    print ('ERROR: Connect failed')
    print ( e )
    quit()
sql = "SELECT * FROM oih"
stmt = IfxPy.exec_immediate(conn, sql)
dictionary = IfxPy.fetch_assoc(stmt)
tph=[]
while dictionary != False:
        tph.append(dictionary)
        dictionary = IfxPy.fetch_assoc(stmt)
print(pd.DataFrame(tph))
```

When I print the dataframe I see that I got only the first 4 rows.

I tried also this code and i doesn't trhow any exception but it returns also the first 4 rows of my table:

```
import IfxPyDbi as dbapi2
ConStr = "SERVER=informix1;DATABASE=ir_fmois;HOST=127.0.0.1;SERVICE=9092;UID=informix;PWD=1234;"
conn = dbapi2.connect( ConStr, "", "")
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM oih"
rows = cur.fetchall()
len(rows)
>>>4
```

**EDIT**

I tried importing columns one by one, and the same error has occured when I tried to select a byte (blob) column (with text data type). This column has emty values in the first 4 rows but the fifth wasn't empty, and I think this is why the error occured in line 5.

I would really appreciate if anyone has any idea on how to solve this.

Comment: Quick test with your code (IfxPy and IfxPyDbi) against a table similar to what you describe (5 rows, all NULL except the last one) and I got no errors. All 5 rows are returned. Both BYTE and BLOB data types work for me so maybe is your data.  If this is still a problem, do what Jonathan suggested, raise an issue in the project page.

Answer (score 0):

The `finderr` command reports:

```
$ finderr -11071
-11071  Invalid string or buffer length.

This Informix CLI error code is the same as SQLSTATE value S1090. The
following functions can return this error code: SQLBindCol(),
SQLBindParameter(), SQLBrowseConnect(), SQLColAttributes(),
SQLColumnPrivileges(), SQLColumns(), SQLConnect(), SQLDataSources(),
SQLDescribeCol(), SQLDriverConnect(), SQLDrivers(), SQLExecDirect(),
SQLExecute(), SQLForeignKeys(), SQLGetCursorName(), SQLGetData(),
SQLGetInfo(), SQLNativeSql(), SQLPrepare(), SQLPrimaryKeys(),
SQLProcedureColumns(), SQLProcedures(), SQLPutData(), SQLSetCursorName(),
SQLSpecialColumns(), SQLStatistics(), SQLTablePrivileges(), and SQLTables().

The value specified for the argument cbValueMax is less than zero.
Supply a value for the argument cbValueMax that is zero or greater.

For all functions, an argument that specified a string or buffer length, such
as cbCursor, cbConnStrIn, or cbSqlStr, had one or more of the following
problems: (1) It was less than 0, (2) It was less than 0 but not equal to
SQL_NTS or SQL_NULL_DATA, (3) It was less than 0 but the corresponding
pointer was not a null pointer, (4) It was equal to 1, or (5) It was too
large. Set the string or buffer length to a valid value.

Additionally for SQLExecDirect() and SQLExecute(), a parameter value that was
set with SQLBindParameter() had one of the following problems: (1) It was a
null pointer, and the parameter length was not 0, SQL_NULL_DATA,
SQL_DATA_AT_EXEC, or less than or equal to SQL_LEN_DATA_AT_EXEC_OFFSET, or
(2) It was not a null pointer, and the parameter length was less than 0 but
was not SQL_NTS, SQL_NULL_DATA, SQL_DATA_AT_EXEC, or less than or equal to
SQL_LEN_EXEC_DATA_AT_EXEC_OFFSET. Set the parameter value to a valid value.

$
```

Since your Python code is not calling any of those functions directly, that suggests there is a bug in the `ifxpy` driver.  It is probably calling one of the listed functions with an incorrect argument.

As such, you should probably report it as an 'issue' on the GitHub site for the driver: https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy